# SQLite - Update a column based on values from two other tables' columns

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to update **Data1**'s **ID** to **Record2**'s **ID** when:

- **Record1**'s and **Record2**'s **Name** are the same, and
- **Weight** is greater in **Record2**.

**Record1**

```
| ID | Weight | Name |
|----|--------|------|
|  1 |     10 |    a |
|  2 |     10 |    b |
|  3 |     10 |    c |
```

**Record2**

```
| ID | Weight | Name |
|----|--------|------|
|  4 |     20 |    a |
|  5 |     20 |    b |
|  6 |     20 |    c |
```

**Data1**

```
| ID | Weight |
|----|--------|
|  4 |     40 |
|  5 |     40 |
```

I have tried the following SQLite query:

```
update data1
set id = 
  (select record2.id 
   from record2,record1 
   where record1.name=record2.name 
   and record1.weight<record2.weight)
where id in
  (select record1.id
   from record1, record2
   where record1.name=record2.name
   and record1.weight<record2.weight)
```

Using the above query **Data1**'s **id** is updated to 4 for all records.

NOTE: **Record1**'s **ID** is the foreign key for **Data1**.

Comment: @CL. This question uses three tables and I am unable to use the same query as provided by you for this one.

Comment: If I write the query as suggested then it does not recognize record1.name

 update data1 
 set id = 
(select record2.id 
from record2
where record1.name=record2.name 
and record1.weight<record2.weight)
where id in
(
select record1.id
from record1
where record1.name=record2.name
and record1.weight<record2.weight)

@CL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given data set the following seems to serve the cause:

```
update data1
set id = 
  (select record2.id 
  from record2,record1 
  where 
   data1.id = record1.id
   and record1.name=record2.name 
   and record1.weight<record2.weight)
where id in
  (select record1.id
  from record1, record2
  where
    record1.id in (select id from data1)
    and record1.name=record2.name 
    and record1.weight<record2.weight)
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4e76e/1).

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Thank you! It worked exactly the way it had to. @Abecee

Comment: @Prabha: Please keep in mind, this would/should/might not work this way, if your remark "Record1's ID is the foreign key for Data1." were enforced at the schema level. However, this doesn't seem to work as [documented](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) - see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/c6926/1).